# transfer value of textbox to php variable

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, wordpress, admin

Hi I am creating a wordpress plugin and i am a little bit stack here. there's text box number 1 which is the order number and number 2 which is the order name. This is what i want. If the customer enters a number in textbox number 1 which is order number, the value he or she entered will check into the database and get the corresponding order name of that order number. Its realtime. No need to submit before it appears. Everytime they input something it will immediate check to the database and display it in text box number 2(order name). I research this and try using ajax in wordpress but i dont know how to use. Thanks.

Comment: Show us your attempt. Ajax is what you're going to want to use.

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/5lxg6v.jpg <-- look at that image

Answer (score 0):

Here's some boilerplate code to get you started....

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var req;

    function handler_orderNumberField_onchange(fld) {
        var text = fld.value;
        if (text.length == 8) {
            queryForOrderName(text);
        }
    }

    function queryForOrderName(orderNumber) {
        document.getElementById('orderNameField').value = "Please wait..."

        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/getordername.php?ordernumber=" + orderNumber;

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var field = document.getElementById('orderNameField');
            var rs = this.readyState;
            var status = this.status;
            if (rs == 4 && status == 200) {
                field.value = req.responseText;
            }
        };

        req.ontimeout = function() {
            document.getElementById('orderNameField').value = 'Timeout.';
        }
        req.timeout = 10000;

        req.open("GET", url, true); 
        req.send();
     }

</script>

<p>Order Number: <input type="text" name="orderNumber" value="" id="orderNumberField" onchange="handler_orderNumberField_onchange(this)"></p>
<p>Order Name: <input type="text" name="orderName" value="" id="orderNameField"></p>
```

Note that you need to implement a `getordername.php` script yourself; example:

```
<?php
    $ordernr = (int) $_GET["ordernumber"];
    $result = sprintf("Testorder - Order Number %d", $ordernr);
    header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    echo $result;
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. but iam using wordpress and i am creating a wordpress plugin. theres some considerations. Can you PLEASE create some codes like this in wordpress

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Which part of that does not work in WordPress? Of course you can't just paste that in, you need to write code in PHP that generates this JS and HTML dynamically.

Comment: THe problem is that i have a form then one of the textbox must check if the input date is in database. thats the problem